# Getting "undefined columns selected" in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a date frame file1, in which col V2 contains time and V3- V13 are the parameters.

I want to plot time vs the parameters in R shiny . I am able to get the summary and table values, But in the plotting it says "undefined columns selected". Any pointer will help.

The Summary and Table values coming as expected

Below is my UI.R and Server.R

```
 - SERVER.R
server <- function(input, output) {
file1 = read.csv(file = "RawData_METHODIST_WOODLANDS_MethodistWoodlands_ YK 
CH1_1_4_2017_to_27_04_2017_new.csv", header = FALSE)
as.data.frame(file1)
# Return the requested dataset ----
file <- reactive({
switch(input$sel, 
       "WAR-CODE ( States )" = file1$V3,
       "VSD-CONVHS-T ( degF )" = file1$V4,
       "MANUAL PRV % OPEN ( % )" = file1$V5,
       "WIND SPEED ( mph )" = file1$V6,
       "REFPOS-SP ( % )" = file1$V7,
       "MOT-FLA ( % )" = file1$V8,
       "LL-SV-STS ( offon )"  = file1$V9,
       "TEMPERATURE ( degF )" = file1$V10,
       "EVAP-P ( psi )" = file1$V11,
       "VSD OP-Hz ( hz )" = file1$V12,
       "MANUAL EVAP RETURN PRESSURE ( psi )" = file1$V13)
  })
# Generate a summary of the dataset ----
output$summary <- renderPrint({
file1 <- file()
summary(file1)
})
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
print(input$sel)
file1 <- file()
file1 <- as.data.frame(file1)
Time1 = strptime(file1$V2,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
plot(Time1,file1[,input$sel])
})
# Show the first "n" observations ----
output$view <- renderTable({
head(file(), n = input$obs)
head(file(), n = input$obs)
})
}

- UI.R

# Define UI for dataset viewer app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

# App title ----
titlePanel("PLOTS FOR JCI"),

# Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions ----
sidebarLayout(

# Sidebar panel for inputs ----
sidebarPanel(

  # Input: Selector for choosing dataset ----
  selectInput(inputId = "sel",
              label = "Choose a Parameter:",
              choices = c("WAR-CODE ( States )" , "VSD-CONVHS-T ( degF )", 
   "MANUAL PRV % OPEN ( % )","WIND SPEED ( mph )","REFPOS-SP ( % )","MOT-FLA 
  ( % )","LL-SV-STS ( offon )","TEMPERATURE ( degF )", "EVAP-P ( psi )","VSD 
  OP-Hz ( hz )","MANUAL EVAP RETURN PRESSURE ( psi )")),
  # Input: Numeric entry for number of obs to view ----
  numericInput(inputId = "obs",
               label = "Number of observations to view:",
               value = 10)
  ),
  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
  mainPanel(
             tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
              tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot1")),
              tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
              tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("view"))
       )
     )
    )
   )
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: I tried and now it gave  "'x' and 'y' lengths differ"

Comment: We can only guest. We can't run your code without file1. Can you make it reproducible?

Comment: plot(Time1,file1$anyparameter) works fine and gives a proper result. But plot(Time1,file1[,input$sel]) didn't work. I want to get the plot of time versus what ever parameter i will select from the drop down list

Comment: @TarunDas, Can you provide a sample data?

Comment: V1                 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10  V11  V12 V13 V14 V15   V16 V17 V18
1 CHILLER1 2017-04-01 0:00:00 10 20 25 30 45 53 80  62 35.5 50.3  54  88  58 119.5  56 536
2 CHILLER1 2017-04-01 0:01:00 10 20 25 30 45 53 80  62 35.5 50.3  54  98  78 159.5  66 536
here V2 is my timestamp which i am stripping to get the date format.and V3 to V18 are my parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked finally. I have used the renderplot() as below.

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot
({  
plot(Time1,file())  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on dummy data:

```
library(shiny)

file1 = data.frame(V1=0:10, V2=12:22, V3=15:25)
Time1 = file1$V2

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(Time1,file1[, input$sel])
  })

}

# Define UI for dataset viewer app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("PLOTS FOR JCI"),

  # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Selector for choosing dataset ----
      selectInput(inputId = "sel",
                  label = "Choose a Parameter:",
                  choices = c("V1" , "V2", "V3"))
    ),
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot1"))
                 )
      )
    )
  )


shinyApp(ui,server)
```