# Error in inherits(min, "Date") : argument "min" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, shinydashboard

The UI.R is

```
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("PLOTS FOR JCI"),

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  helpText("JCI PLOTTING
           information from Chiller Data"),

  selectInput("sel", 
              label = "Choose a variable to display",
              choices = c("WAR-CODE ( States )" , "VSD-CONVHS-T ( 
             degF )", "MANUAL PRV % OPEN ( % )",
                          "WIND SPEED ( mph )","REFPOS-SP ( % )","MOT-
             FLA ( % )",
                          "LL-SV-STS ( offon )","TEMPERATURE ( degF )", 
            "EVAP-P ( psi )",
                          "VSD OP-Hz ( hz )","MANUAL EVAP RETURN 
             PRESSURE ( psi )")),
              selected = "WAR-CODE ( States )"),

             sliderInput("range", 
             label = "Number of observations to view:",
             value = 10)
             ),

             mainPanel(plotOutput("map"))
             )
```

Please help if there is any solution. I am not using min function here. tried to clear the environment still getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because you are missing `min` and `max` arguments in your `sliderInput`. Your `sliderInput` should be something like this:

```
sliderInput("range", 
                label = "Number of observations to view:",
                value = 10, min = 0, max = 20)
    )
```

Comment: It wroked out !!

Comment: can you please also help me in the below question too. I was trying to do get a plot on the below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207651/getting-undefined-columns-selected-in-r-shiny?noredirect=1#comment83397045_48207651

Comment: @TarunDas, could you please accept the answer? Also, the question you directed me to already has an answer.

Comment: Yes, the answer you shared worked out. any help to the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207651/getting-undefined-columns-selected-in-r-shiny?noredirect=1#comment83397045_48207651                       will be of great help